# Python error from QuickOSM plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, quickosm

I cannot run the QuickOSM plugin in QGIS. I have tried reinstalling the plugin, even upgraded to another version of QGIS.

I get this error message:

> Python error: An error has occurred while executing Python code: See message log (Python Error) for more details.

This is the log from Python error :

```
2023-01-01T07:56:54     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\quick_osm.py", line 253, in open_dialog
  dialog = Dialog()
  File "C:\Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\dialog.py", line 205, in __init__
  panel.setup_panel()
  File "C:\Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\quick_query_panel.py", line 134, in setup_panel
  self.update_history_view()
  File "C:\Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\quick_query_panel.py", line 304, in update_history_view
  data = json.load(json_file, object_hook=as_enum)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
  return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 359, in loads
  return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
 json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Which versions of QGIS have you tried?

Comment: I tried it in 3.22.11-Białowieża. I updated to this version because of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is not in the your
plugin "core" directory, so reinstalling the plugin won't solve the issue. The issue is your "QuickOSM" folder from your profile, where the plugin is storing YOUR settings.

Removing this folder will help, because I can't know your current issue.

"Preferences" -> "Profiles" -> "Open current profile folder", open in the "QuickOSM" directory visible -> "query_history". One file in your history is broken. You can remove them.

Source: I'm the QuickOSM developer.

Comment: Thankyou.. Doing that solved my problem. I removed all the files in C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QuickOSM\query_history directory

Comment: @ujjwalbasnet kindly accept this as answer.